# Loading a MATLAB table file as Array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, matlab

I am currently building a test server for an Web-Application, which is supposed to feed it fake data via a Websocket. The fake data is inside a MATLAB table file (.mat). The mat file is basically just a 4000*192 array. I would like to map it into an javascript array so I can iterate over it and send column by column to the client.

I just do not know how to convert MATLAB table to an javascript array inside Node.js. All the libraries i have found do not support node.js, because of how jdataview handles node buffers.

Comment: Is `.mat` a requirement? MATLAB can also use low-level write routines, such as [`fprintf()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to output binaries, CSV or whatever file format which is probably easier to read.

Comment: It seems from this page https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98947-is-it-possible-to-read-write-mat-files-from-a-c-application that API's only exist for fortran and c/c++. You can integrate c++ into a node application, perhaps that's an option here, but it seems that @Adriaan's suggestion would be preferrable

Comment: unfortunatly i only have the .mat file ...

Comment: Did you ever try this one - https://github.com/fluffynukeit/jMatFile

Comment: yeah, that one does not support node.js

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm think you are wrong. Try `npm install https://github.com/fluffynukeit/jMatFile.git jbinary`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to load the .mat file. As Vasyl previously mentioned, the following git repository is your best bet - [Read Mat File](https://github.com/fluffynukeit/jMatFile)

Please try this -

```
var jBinary = require('jbinary')
var MAT = require('jMatFile')

jBinary.load('myMat.mat', MAT).then(function (binary) {
  var mat = binary.readAll
  // or equivalently
  var mat = binary.read('mat')
})
```

I was able to load the data to console, but am struggling with something else right now.

It also says in the document that the typeset only works with JS engines that fully support typed arrays. As of 4 years ago (repo last updated), the restriction knowingly excludes:

- phantomjs because it does not support Float64Array
- nodejs because of jdataview's special treatment of node Buffers

You are also going to have to install jMatFile which isn't in the npm directory, which again, Vasyl was right to point out in the previous comments. Run these before you do the usual 'npm start' -

```
npm i jBinary
```

and

```
npm i https://github.com/fluffynukeit/jMatFile.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this module: https://github.com/KovacsGG/mat4js

Install it like so:

```
npm i mat-for-js
```

Example code:

```
import fs from "fs";
import { read as readmat } from "mat-for-js";

fs.readFile("my_file.mat", null, (err, data) => {
    let final = readmat(data.buffer);
    console.log(final);
});
```